# How can I create a sound fade out effect

Tags: java, audio, fade, midi

using this code

```
for (int k = 0; k < 16; k++) {
    Track track = musicS.createTrack();
    track.add(new MidiEvent(new ShortMessage(ShortMessage.CONTROL_CHANGE, k, 7, 20), track.ticks() -3));
}
```

How can I make the volume fade out  **right before the song ends**

Answer (score 1):

Looking [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19012672/track-add-midievent-and-shortmessage-volume-control), it looks like you may want to set the ticks for the MidiEvent to be something like (track.getTicks() - someNumberOfTicks) to change the volume for the end of the song.

Answer (score 0):

How many ticks are there in your Track?

You need to add a lot of MidiEvents to the end of you track, starting with where you want the fade to begin, gradually lowering the volume for each event.

Your code snippet is setting the volume at tick 0. Do you know if you are setting 7 to 'volume' or 'volume' to 7?

You need a new loop to add your MidiEvents to the end of your track.

Comment: volume didn't exist, I just wasn't sure what I was doing 

I don't really understand where I'm supposed to be adding these  MidiEvents and why I need so many

Comment: A MIDI track is made up of a bunch of discreet events similar to notes in a piece of music. The only way to do a fade with MIDI is to create a bunch of "set my volume to x" events and keep making x smaller and smaller. If you only made 2 events that set volume to 3 then to 0, it wouldn't be a fade, you would hear the volume just drop once and then go silent.

If you aren't that familiar with programming it'll probably be easier for you to just export to audio and add a fade with a separate tool like audacity.

Comment: The thing is, once I understand it, I'll be able to use it in the future, that's why I'm so persistent on trying to understand this.

Is there any chance you could help me one on one? Through Skype or by other means?

Comment: Is your code to the point where you can hear the midi output? It sounds like you might need more help than I can give you.

Comment: You can hear the sounds, I'm only having trouble with the fading